# Ошибка с подключением google map для приложения на react.js

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, reactjs, google-maps, meteor

Я разрабатываю приложение на `meteor.js` и мне нужно подключить скрипт с `Google maps` только для одной страницы с картами. Я подключаю его в конструкторе класса.

```
class Map extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API-KEY&callback=initMap";
    script.async = true;
    script.defer = true;
    document.head.appendChild(script);

    this.panToArcDeTriomphe = this.panToArcDeTriomphe.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.refs.map, 
       { center: {lat:48.858608, lng:2.294471}, zoom:16 }
    );
  }
  panToArcDeTriomphe() {
    console.log(this)
    this.map.panTo({ lat:48.873947, lng:2.295038});
  }
  render() {
    const mapStyle = {width:500, height:300, border:'1px solid black' };    
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.panToArcDeTriomphe}>Go to</button>
        <div ref="map" style={mapStyle}>I should be a map</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Map />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Но получаю такую ошибку:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

Код этого примера на codepen:
http://codepen.io/alex183/pen/XpJJPz?editors=0011

Не могу понять в чем проблема, на странице скрипт виден, но при этом карты не работают.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Случаем, библиотека у вас подключается не после скрипта, в котором используется?

Comment: Какая библиотека? Вроде ничего лишнего не подключаю, конструктор я так понимаю инициализируеться первым, поле него все остальное. Скрипт вроде на странице рисуется но на этом все. Не работает.

Comment: Повторюсь, вы используете `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js` ДО или ПОСЛЕ того, как подключили? Скрипт с ее использованием выше или ниже в DOM дереве?

Comment: Сейчас вставил в head в любом случае все остальные скрипты идут ниже. Если я правильно понял вопрос. Картинку обновил.

Comment: И все же остается вероятность, что библиотека не успела загрузиться, добавленная таким образом.

Comment: Вполне возможно, но что в таком случае делать я не совсем понимаю,  кроме вставки где нибудь setTimeout  других мыслей у меня нет. Подключить традиционным способом в данном стеке возможности нет.

Comment: Так воспользуйтесь библиотекой для стека. Например https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps

Comment: Под стеком я имел в виду `meteor.js` а не только `react.js`. И не хочется тащить еще одну очередную библиотек по сути за ради подключения `google map api`.

Comment: Так вы можете посмотреть, как там библиотека добавляется и перенять только это.

Comment: Могу, но там довольно запутанно все выглядит на 150 строчек https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/blob/master/lib/async/withScriptjs.js которые просто скопипастить не получится и в моем случае за вечер возможно тоже не получится осилить. Поэтому и хотелось немного проще решить проблему задав вопрос.

Comment: Привел решение ниже, вообщем надо было еще колбек добавить подгружающему скрипту.

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

```
class Map extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.panToArcDeTriomphe = this.panToArcDeTriomphe.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=api_key&callback=initMap";
    loadScript(url, ()=>{
      this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.refs.map, { center:{ lat:48.858608, lng:2.294471 }, zoom:16});
    })
  }
  panToArcDeTriomphe() {
    console.log(this);
    this.map.panTo({ lat:48.873947, lng:2.295038 });
  }
  render() {
    const mapStyle = {width:500, height:300, border:'1px solid black'};
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.panToArcDeTriomphe}>Go to</button>
        <div ref="map" style={mapStyle}>I should be a map</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function loadScript(url, callback) {
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = url;
  script.onreadystatechange = callback;
  script.onload = callback;
  head.appendChild(script);
}
```